# Change the color of text within a pandas dataframe html table python using styles and css

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
arrays = [['Midland', 'Midland', 'Hereford', 'Hereford', 'Hobbs','Hobbs', 'Childress',
           'Childress', 'Reese', 'Reese', 'San Angelo', 'San Angelo'],
          ['WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 4), index=arrays,
                  columns=['00 UTC', '06 UTC', '12 UTC', '18 UTC'])
```

The table that prints `df` from this looks like this:[image]

I would like to color all of the values in the 'MOS' rows a certain color and color the left two index/header columns as well as the top header row a different background color than the rest of the cells with values in them. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This takes a few steps:

First import `HTML` and `re`

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import re
```

You can get at the `html` pandas puts out via the `to_html` method.

```
df_html = df.to_html()
```

Next we are going to generate a random identifier for the html table and style we are going to create.

```
random_id = 'id%d' % np.random.choice(np.arange(1000000))
```

Because we are going to insert some style, we need to be careful to specify that this style will only be for our table.  Now let's insert this into the `df_html`

```
df_html = re.sub(r'<table', r'<table id=%s ' % random_id, df_html)
```

And create a style tag.  This is really up to you.  I just added some hover effect.

```
style = """
<style>
    table#{random_id} tr:hover {{background-color: #f5f5f5}}
</style>
""".format(random_id=random_id)
```

Finally, display it

```
HTML(style + df_html)
```

#### Function all in one.

```
def HTML_with_style(df, style=None, random_id=None):
    from IPython.display import HTML
    import numpy as np
    import re

    df_html = df.to_html()

    if random_id is None:
        random_id = 'id%d' % np.random.choice(np.arange(1000000))

    if style is None:
        style = """
        <style>
            table#{random_id} {{color: blue}}
        </style>
        """.format(random_id=random_id)
    else:
        new_style = []
        s = re.sub(r'</?style>', '', style).strip()
        for line in s.split('\n'):
                line = line.strip()
                if not re.match(r'^table', line):
                    line = re.sub(r'^', 'table ', line)
                new_style.append(line)
        new_style = ['<style>'] + new_style + ['</style>']

        style = re.sub(r'table(#\S+)?', 'table#%s' % random_id, '\n'.join(new_style))

    df_html = re.sub(r'<table', r'<table id=%s ' % random_id, df_html)

    return HTML(style + df_html)
```

Use it like this:

```
HTML_with_style(df.head())
```

[image]

```
HTML_with_style(df.head(), '<style>table {color: red}</style>')
```

[image]

```
style = """
<style>
    tr:nth-child(even) {color: green;}
    tr:nth-child(odd)  {color: aqua;}
</style>
"""
HTML_with_style(df.head(), style)
```

[image]

Learn CSS and go nuts!

Comment: I have never used HTML before so I apologize if this is a simple question, but when I type this exact same function into my ipython notebook cell the table looks exactly the same as it did before. Is there something else I need to do or change to make it display with different colors and such?

Comment: May I ask you one stupid question - how do you save output cell as a picture in Jupyter? I have almost zero experience with Jupyter and couldn't figure it out yet... Thank you!

Comment: @MaxU I take screenshots every time

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you! I thought there is an easy magic method that i can't find in Jupyter... :-D

Comment: @MaxU it's funny but the 4-key combination is burned into my muscle memory

Comment: @MaxU Command + Control + Shift + 4: enables me to drag a rectangle and puts screenshot into clipboard.  OS X

Comment: @piRSquared - Is it possible to assign **tags/ids** to html table rows and cells generated using `df.to_html()`?

Answer (score 29):

Using pandas new [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) functionality (*since 0.17.1*):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['Midland', 'Midland', 'Hereford', 'Hereford', 'Hobbs','Hobbs', 'Childress',
           'Childress', 'Reese', 'Reese', 'San Angelo', 'San Angelo'],
          ['WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS','WRF','MOS']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 4), index=arrays,
                  columns=['00 UTC', '06 UTC', '12 UTC', '18 UTC'])


def highlight_MOS(s):
    is_mos = s.index.get_level_values(1) == 'MOS'
    return ['color: darkorange' if v else 'color: darkblue' for v in is_mos]

s = df.style.apply(highlight_MOS)
s
```

[image]