# Color numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is there a way to print some numbers in a dataframe in a different color?
So for instance if I wanted to have the 1 in the following table in red. How can I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
A=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
```

I found libraries like termcolor. But there I can only print normal text in various colors.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38511805/2336654

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer @piRSquared provided which gives great ability for granular control, it appears `pandas` has added a [style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) feature as of `0.17.1` for addressing this exact issue. Here is a slightly modified version of the example provided in the linked documentation.

[image]

Comment: @Merlin Yes I generally do that, although since this is rendering in a notebook (to get the html highlighting) it is a bit difficult. I guess I could have copied the code separately but for this short snippet it seemed unecessary