# How to return a specific cell that have color style and font style for iloc[1,1] only?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and below is my color code:

```
   def color (val):
    if final.iloc[1,1]<final.iloc[1,0]:
        return "background-color: green"
    else:
        return "background-color: red"
```

I wish to return only `final.iloc[1,1]` to have green color background, if above code was apply, my whole data frame become green color already.

I also wish the `final.iloc[1,1]` able to change the font style, anyone can share me some idea?

Comment: this might be of some help....http://stackoverflow.com/q/38511373/6524169

Comment: not able, I try already but in my case I need only one cell not the overall whole dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
df =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
print (df)

def highlight_col(x):
    #copy df to new - original data are not changed
    df = x.copy()
    #set default values to all values
    df.loc[:,:] = 'background-color: ""'
    #set by condition
    if x.iloc[1,1]<x.iloc[1,0]:
        df.iloc[1,1] = 'background-color: red'
    else:
        df.iloc[1,1] = 'background-color: green'
    return df    

df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
```

Comment: Still not able , I get this error   **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'style'**

Comment: Can you try edited answer. Previous solution was wrong.

Comment: I try to apply this `df.iloc[1,1] = 'background-color: red' ` also not able this error was shown **'unorderable types: str() < float()',**

Comment: For red color use `np.random.seed(170)`

Comment: yes I try but get this error**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'**

Comment: Error is with my sample data?

Comment: and what is your pandas version? `print  (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: I not sure , no matter how I edit, I get this error always **NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'**  , my pandas version is 0.19.2

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ex1 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 4],
        [5, 3, 1]
    ], list('ABC'), list('XYZ'))

ex2 = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 9, 4],
        [5, 3, 1]
    ], list('ABC'), list('XYZ'))

def hl(x):
    r = 'background-color: red'
    g = 'background-color: green'
    c = g if x.iloc[1, 1] < x.iloc[1, 0] else r
    y = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    y.iloc[1, 1] = c
    return y
```

---

```
ex1.style.apply(hl, axis=None)
```

[image]

```
ex2.style.apply(hl, axis=None)
```

[image]