# Is there a quick way to turn a pandas DataFrame into a pretty HTML table?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, jupyter

Problem: the output of `df.to_html()` is a plain html table, which isn't much to look at:

[image: ugly table]

Meanwhile, the visual representation of dataframes in the Jupyter Notebook is much nicer, but if there's an easy way to replicate it, I haven't found it.

[image: pretty table]

I know it should be possible to generate a more aesthetically-pleasing table by fiddling around with `df.style`, but before I go off learning CSS, has anyone already written a function to do this?

Comment: Here's some info you might be able to use: [https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html)

Comment: @cosinepenguin I don't see anything about pandas in there...

Comment: Since `pandas` 0.17.1, lot's of styling options have been added. Check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider my dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), list('ABC'), list('XYZ'))

df

   X  Y  Z
A  0  1  2
B  3  4  5
C  6  7  8
```

I ripped this style off of my jupyter notebook

```
my_style = """background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: table;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 1675px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 12px;
table-layout: fixed;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
width: 700px;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"""
```

I got this from [**my post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38511805/2336654)

```
def HTML_with_style(df, style=None, random_id=None):
    from IPython.display import HTML
    import numpy as np
    import re

    df_html = df.to_html()

    if random_id is None:
        random_id = 'id%d' % np.random.choice(np.arange(1000000))

    if style is None:
        style = """
        <style>
            table#{random_id} {{color: blue}}
        </style>
        """.format(random_id=random_id)
    else:
        new_style = []
        s = re.sub(r'</?style>', '', style).strip()
        for line in s.split('\n'):
                line = line.strip()
                if not re.match(r'^table', line):
                    line = re.sub(r'^', 'table ', line)
                new_style.append(line)
        new_style = ['<style>'] + new_style + ['</style>']

        style = re.sub(r'table(#\S+)?', 'table#%s' % random_id, '\n'.join(new_style))

    df_html = re.sub(r'<table', r'<table id=%s ' % random_id, df_html)

    return HTML(style + df_html)
```

Then I implement

```
HTML_with_style(df, '<style>table {{{}}}</style>'.format(my_style))
```

[image]

You can modify the code to dump the html

```
def HTML_with_style(df, style=None, random_id=None):
    import numpy as np
    import re

    df_html = df.to_html()

    if random_id is None:
        random_id = 'id%d' % np.random.choice(np.arange(1000000))

    if style is None:
        style = """
        <style>
            table#{random_id} {{color: blue}}
        </style>
        """.format(random_id=random_id)
    else:
        new_style = []
        s = re.sub(r'</?style>', '', style).strip()
        for line in s.split('\n'):
                line = line.strip()
                if not re.match(r'^table', line):
                    line = re.sub(r'^', 'table ', line)
                new_style.append(line)
        new_style = ['<style>'] + new_style + ['</style>']

        style = re.sub(r'table(#\S+)?', 'table#%s' % random_id, '\n'.join(new_style))

    df_html = re.sub(r'<table', r'<table id=%s ' % random_id, df_html)

    return style + df_html
```

And now

```
HTML_with_style(df, '<style>table {{{}}}</style>'.format(my_style))

'<style>\ntable#id850184 {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 border-bottom-style: none;\ntable#id850184 border-bottom-width: 0px;\ntable#id850184 border-collapse: collapse;\ntable#id850184 border-image-outset: 0px;\ntable#id850184 border-image-repeat: stretch;\ntable#id850184 border-image-slice: 100%;\ntable#id850184 border-image-source: none;\ntable#id850184 border-image-width: 1;\ntable#id850184 border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 border-left-style: none;\ntable#id850184 border-left-width: 0px;\ntable#id850184 border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 border-right-style: none;\ntable#id850184 border-right-width: 0px;\ntable#id850184 border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 border-top-style: none;\ntable#id850184 border-top-width: 0px;\ntable#id850184 box-sizing: border-box;\ntable#id850184 color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\ntable#id850184 display: table#id850184;\ntable#id850184 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\ntable#id850184 font-size: 12px;\ntable#id850184 height: 1675px;\ntable#id850184 line-height: 20px;\ntable#id850184 margin-left: 0px;\ntable#id850184 margin-right: 0px;\ntable#id850184 margin-top: 12px;\ntable#id850184-layout: fixed;\ntable#id850184 text-size-adjust: 100%;\ntable#id850184 width: 700px;\ntable#id850184 -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;\ntable#id850184 -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;\ntable#id850184 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}\n</style><table id=id850184  border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>X</th>\n      <th>Y</th>\n      <th>Z</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>A</th>\n      <td>0</td>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>B</th>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n      <td>5</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>C</th>\n      <td>6</td>\n      <td>7</td>\n      <td>8</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

Answer (score 14):

After some research I found the **prettiest and easiest** solution to be https://pypi.org/project/pretty-html-table/

```py
import pandas as pd
from pretty_html_table import build_table
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), list('ABC'), list('XYZ'))
html_table_blue_light = build_table(df, 'blue_light')
print(html_table_blue_light)
with open('styled_table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_table_blue_light)
```

Comment: Do you know how can we reduce the size of font in html table? upvoted for this solution

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. You can pass `build_table(df, 'blue_light', font_size='25px')`. See for example https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_size.asp for more ways to declare `font-size` in `html`

Answer (score 3):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jupyter.org/notebook/5.1.0/style/style.min.css">`

you need to add `class="rendered_html"` to `<body>` otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could also add the following Raw NBConvert cell at the top of your notebook:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jupyter.org/notebook/5.1.0/style/style.min.css">
```

NBConvert seems to fail adding these styles into the exported HTML. The line above will add them explicitly.

[Source](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/283#issuecomment-391666943)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pretty_html_table import build_table
df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
html_table_blue_light = build_table(df, 'blue_light')
```